# Running Windows 7 and Server 2012 on the same machine simultaneously

Tags: sql-server, windows-7-x64, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2

I want to simultaneously run SQL Server 2012 and Windows 7 on the same machine. My computer is currently configured to dual boot into either Windows 7 Professional or Server 2012 R2.

I am running software that requires a SQL Server database to connect to and want to create an all-encompassing machine that can do all of this, for research & demo purposes.

Is this possible? I know I can do this with two computers over a network, but that's not really a proper long term solution. Other workarounds and suggestions are valuable to me as well. I can obtain just about any hardware or software that allows this.

Comment: Please search for the term _virtual machine_...

Answer (score 2):

It is **impossible** to commmunicate between two operating systems installed as Dual Boot as only one it is running in any given moment.

**Possible solutions** (you should go for solution 1)

1. In your Windows 7 (or in the Windows Server 2012) you should install
   **both** your software and SQL Server 2012
2. If is not possible to run **both** in the same Windows (not your case) you can use virtual machines (i.e: VirtualBox) and have your
   Windows communicate to the VM by internal virtual network.

Answer (score 1):

Installation of Sql server 2012 on windows 7 is fully supported. You don't need a windows server in order to install it, so you can boot your W7 partition and install directly there.